# Android Studio: New tv project inserts merge lines into AndroidManifest.xml and is not well formed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

I am using the latest version of Android Studio 0.8.14.

After creating a new project for tv with android 5.0, I get a gradle error stating.

```
  The markup in the document proceding the root element must be well-formed
  Problem was found with the config task app:generateDebugBuildConfig
```

After taking a look in the androidmanifest I notice some issues. This is a brand new project. Any ideas ?

I am placing the manifest below, you can plainly see the Orginal and Added words. Seems to have been some merge issue or something ??

I tried removing the Original and the invalid markup. But that didnt seem to work. I get an error now saying

"Manifest merger failed : Main AndroidManifest.xml at AndroidManifest.xml manifest:package attribute is not declared"

Here is the original manifest, untouched.

```
<<<<<<< Original
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testme.myapplication">

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>

=======
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
                        android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"
            android:allowBackup="false">

        <activity android:name="com.testme.myapplication.MainActivity"
            android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_quantum"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="PlayerActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <activity android:name="com.testme.myapplication.DetailsActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
>>>>>>> Added
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should delete following part:

```
<<<<<<< Original
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testme.myapplication">

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>

=======
```

and delete this line at the end too:

```
>>>>>>> Added
```

Android Studio generates manifest for different devices and merges with the old one, but I don't know why, it doesnt delete the default generated manifest for mobile devices.

Edit: you may want to add this to your new manifest as well, to avoid missing package name:

package="com.testme.myapplication"

Answer (score 0):

You can have just one  element in your [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file.

In addition, the two manifest declarations differ in the "package" attribute.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.testme.myapplication">

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
```

All in all, you have a malformed AndroidManifest file. Fix that and the demo project will compile just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes true, but this is a new project created from the template. Must be a bug in Android Studio, then ?

Comment: I created several demo TV projects with Studio 0.8.9, haven't seen anything like that. I'll try tomorrow with 0.8.14 and then get back to you.